# Fail to import/copy database from old installation (database) of WAMP for wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wamp

My WAMP server crashed a few days ago and so I uninstalled and reinstalled it. However I changed the default installation location. I then moved the backup folder of wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17/data and also the /www/ folder to the new installation folder. The I reinstalled wordpress and it gave me WordPress database error. I tried installing Apache and MySQL manually but that didn't work. 
Any help will be highly appreciated!

Here is what I have done:

1. I installed wamp on my G:\ Drive which has a path of G:\wamp, before it crashed, I backed up the 
   folder in case I would need it.
2. Since it has crashed, I uninstalled wamp and reinstalled it but this time I set the installation path to another folder E:\wamp.
3. I then copied and pasted the backup folder to E:\wamp.
4. I went to phpmyadmin, the database are all there.
5. Then I tried accessing wordpress (localhost/mysite, say mysite is the www/mysite wordpress folder)
6. I followed the instruction to reinstall wordpress, but i likely got the login user and pw messed up.
7. But all I got is database error.
8. I only want to import the data in wp_posts.ibd to the new installation. Of course it would be good if my wordpress can be fully restored.

Please help!

Comment: To be able to help you are going to have to be MUCH more specific about what you did.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Let my try to explain what I have done above:

Answer (score 0):

Ok that is much more clear and it identifies the problem.

When WampServer installs, part of the install process modifies some of the base files with the location of where you installed it. So when you copied the files that were originally installed on G:\wamp to the new install on E:\wamp everything gets VERY COMFUSED.

Here is what you should do :-

Uninstall the E:\wamp install, and then manually delete the E:\wamp folder completely. The uninstall wont remove any files that it didnt install or files it did install that have changed since the install.

Now reinstall WampServer into `E:\wamp`. Check that this all works before doing anything else i.e. check you get the WAMPServer homepage when you run `localhost` and that phpMyAdmin runs.

Now to recover the databases you have, copy these from your backup.

First stop WampServer, then copy

```
backup:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysqlx.y.z to E:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysqlx.y.z
```

To get your websites back, assuming they are in various subfolders of `\wamp\www\`, copy

```
backup:\wamp\www\subfolder to E:\wamp\www\subfolder
```

This will restore YOUR files, Websites and Databases without effecting any of WAMPServers own files.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I just tried the above method, but wordpress still asked me to install again and then I get Database error...
is there just any way I can extract data from the ibd files?